# Naming UI components in web based editor

Tags: gui

I'm developing a web-based source code editor. I'm developing everything(tabs, context menu etc) out of HTML elements. How do I come up with names for UI controls? Is there a book or guide or project from which I can learn how to name things?

Answer (score 5):

I agree with most of what greengit says, but like to add the following. The bottom line is indeed to ensure readability. That's why I prefer not to use abbreviations like `btn`, `dlg`, etc. I've seen this lead to unreadable abbreviations (i.e. what's `icb`, it was a custom control, but definitely unreadable).

Also, I like to put the function of the control first.

So: `SignupButton`, `AddLink`, `RegistrationDialog`, etc.

Do choose something you feel comfortable with, go for readability, and stick to it. Consistency also increases readability.

Comment: I like to prefix with the type. Most of the time, I know the type I am searching for but forgot the exact business-name I gave to the control. So with tools like Intellisense it's easier to find the control when using a prefix-notation.

Comment: @Mark Booth: Not for me. When I look at the business-logical element I immediatelly can tell the input device. I'm a strong advocate of the prefixing of UI-Elements with the typename. We can start a holy war about it, if you like! ;)

Comment: @Mark Booth: This is totally independent of language imho. After all, you, as a programmer, choose the names. In C# I call my button ButtonAddCustomer for example.

Comment: I suspect there are subtle style-differences across languages. For example, in C#, one would expect Pascal- or CamelCasing, but in HTML, this isn't so widely accepted. In the end, you should choose what you're most comfortable with. This is a little harder sometimes on bigger teams.

Comment: @Mark Booth: There is a strong correlation and conventions should be meaningful. We've got our own conventions here and some of the points may even conflict with Microsoft's suggestions, but that's not a problem. btw: submit_Button is against C# conventions, too. We choose that convention because it works for us best and it's also a little easier to process by machines.

Comment: @Mark Booth: Also, thanks for the chat invitation, but not right now. Someday, maybe :)

Comment: As much as anything else, the chat invitation was a prompt to clean up the comments here, we aren't really helping Peter to improve his answer with this discussion, especially (as you say) this is holy war territory.